# Firefox nested iframes and Flash video problems

Tags: macos, firefox, firefox-9

Am seeing an issue with Firefox 9.0.1 (so far in Mac only) in which if there's content in a nested iframe of the kind:

Main file:

```
<iframe src="testFF1.html" width=600 height=800>
</iframe>
```

testFF1.html:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/DAl5nv7tIR4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

So far am unable to show a different video on the second iframe, it always shows the same one, no matter which address I use.

You can see the issue here:

http://crashdummy.meetai.com/testFF.html

If I edit the second file (testFF1.html), i.e. to display another video, I have to restart FF in order to see the change.

Comment: Could it be related to: [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=388714)?

Answer (score 0):

Your cache header has testFF1.html expiring in 2 weeks.  Have you tried doing a forced reload in FF (shift-f5?)

BTW, You really should post an example that allows others to repro the problem.

Comment: Hi, the example on the question (testFF.html) doesn't suffice? I cleared the entire browser cache and it didn't work. I had to close and re-open the browser.

Did you try to reproduce with OSX-FF?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this at the end. There is a problem with the isotope jQuery plugin and the translate3d positioning when using these iframes. I don't know why it works for other content.